# Update column value PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update the value of a column where it matches a certain `userid`, but it keeps giving a syntax error.

```
UPDATE user 
   SET balance = 15000.000000000 
 WHERE id = 11203;
```

The table called user has many rows with two columns, `balance` and `id`. I am trying to edit the balance of the user id in the code.

Comment: Post the `create table` statement.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try "user", or give a more generic name:

```
UPDATE "user" 
 SET balance = 15000.000000000 
 WHERE id = 11203;
```

or `ALTER` your table name to "user_list" for example. Any doubt, please check
[keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Answer (score 18):

You need to escape `user` since it is a reserved word. Try

```
UPDATE "user"
SET balance = 15000.000000000 
WHERE id = 11203;
```